# SOwhat Stack Overflow browser

Tags: app, qt, c++

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

SOwhat is a Qt-based application that attempts to mimic the Stack Overflow website.

#### License

SOwhat is released under the [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

#### Download

Currently, this is what I can offer:
**Linux 64-bit:** http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/SOwhat/SOwhat_linux.tar.gz
**Linux 32-bit:** http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/SOwhat/SOwhat_linux_32.tar.gz
**Windows 32-bit:** http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/SOwhat/SOwhat_alpha.zip

#### Platform

Any platform supported by Qt.

### Contact

I can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com.

### Code

The source code for SOwhat can be found at:
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/SOwhat_source.tar.gz

Comment: That's purty!!!

Comment: Any chance of a Mercurial repo? I'm willing to set it up / host it (I'm an admin at sharesource.org)

Comment: @Tim: Sure! That'd be awesome. If you would send me a link of the repo page to the email address above, that would be great.

Comment: @George nice work!!

Comment: @George - Have you picked a license yet? (kind of needed to set that up) .. or lets pick this up in e-mail?

Comment: If you want to use Mercurial, why not host it on Codeplex?

Comment: @Tim: I'm thinking of going with the MIT license.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to use or write such an app.

Comment: @ripper: To test my C++ wrapper.

Comment: @George Edison: Sorry to be a nuisance, but I'm afraid the source tarball is incomplete (ui and ./sopp missing). Can I get a full set somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: @Ekkehard: `sopp` is an external library available [here](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/). The `.ui` file is [here](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/temp/mainwindow.ui).

Comment: All of the download links seem to be broken.

Comment: @Novice: it wouldn't work anyway, unfortunately. Version 1.0 of the API was shut down a few months ago.