# Any CSS ninjas want to help me style my sample app?

Tags: discussion, c#, jquery

I really am horrible at CSS. I am making a SO clone example application that will eventually consume as much of the [StackOverflow.Net API](https://stackapps.com/questions/6/stackoverflow-net-client-library) as possible. Although it is a clone, I am not expecting it to look like SO, so whoever would like to work on this (and get mad props) can go all out. I would also be interested in somebody who would like to do some client side "stuff". In quotes, because I have not defined what that stuff would be. So if there is any interest hit me up at cejenkin at gmail, or start a discussion at the [project site](http://stackoverflow.codeplex.com/). You will need VS 2010 with MVC 2.

Comment: Are you making something like this: http://stackapps.com/questions/39/

Comment: 'Cuz I used a lot of CSS for that.

Comment: @George It is a browser, right now there is virtually no styles applied. It doesn't need to look like SO at all, if it ends up that way great, but that is not a requirement. Preview: http://picasaweb.google.com/cejenkin/StackApps#5477496221463279810

Comment: I think I might be able to help. Mail me more details at simon.aronsson, also gmail.